# Displaying currency formatted numbers from an array in dynamic text fields (Flash AS )

Tags: android, actionscript-3, air, flash-cs5

I am working on an AIR or Android application that loads data from a CSV file and displays that data in dynamic text boxes.

Some of the fields in the CSV files are numbers and I can't get them currency formatted and displayed in dynamic text fields.

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.text.*;
import flashx.textLayout.formats.Float;

function internationalFormat(number:Number):String {
    return String(number).replace(".", ",").replace(String(number).indexOf(".") > -1 ?/(?<=\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d)(?:\,\d*))/g : /(?<=\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, ".").replace(/\.{2,}/g, ".");
}

var toFixed:Function = function(number, factor) {
    return (Math.round(number * factor)/factor);
}

var tf1:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
tf1.font ="Arial Rounded MT Bold";
tf1.size = 20;
tf1.align = "left";

var img1Requestf:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://www.maineventjamaica.com/digicelpad/photo.png");
var img1Loaderf:Loader = new Loader();
img1Loaderf.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete);
img1Loaderf.load(img1Requestf);
_1.addChild(img1Loaderf);
stop();
//CSV PATH
var myRequest1:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://www.maineventjamaica.com/digicelpad/table_database_final.csv");

//Load ARRAY
var loadedData1:Array = [];
//loader variable
var myLoader1 = new URLLoader();

myLoader1.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onload1);

myLoader1.load(myRequest1);

function onload1(Event):void

{

//Now, lets put each row into its own array. To do that, we split the data by /\r\n|\n|\r/, which is a RegExp pattern that works with CSV files that can be created on all platforms (Windows puts \r\n between variables, Mac puts \r and Linux puts \n).
loadedData1 = myLoader1.data.split(/\r\n|\n|\r/);

for (var i:int=0; i<loadedData1.length; i++){
loadedData1[i] = loadedData1[i].split(",");
//Number(loadedData1[i].attributes.time.toString())
}

//var sprice:Number = loadedData1[1][5];

//var test:Number = loadedData1[1][5];

//Testing datatype convertion
//var myInt:int = parseInt(loadedData1[1][5]);
//var myFloat:Number = parseFloat(loadedData1[1][5]);
var number:Number = Number(loadedData1[1][5]);

trace(internationalFormat(number));
//-trace(loadedData1[1][5]);


myTXTh0.text = Number("$" + trace(internationalFormat(number)));
trace(myTXTh0.text);
myTXTh1.text = String("$" + loadedData1[1][3]);
myTXTh2.text = String(loadedData1[1][6]);
//myTXTh3.text = String(loadedData1[1][8]);
//myTXTh4.text = String(loadedData1[1][7]);
myTXTh5.text = String(loadedData1[1][4]);


myTXTh0.defaultTextFormat = tf1;
myTXTh1.defaultTextFormat = tf1;
myTXTh2.defaultTextFormat = tf1;
//myTXTh3.defaultTextFormat = tf1;
//myTXTh4.defaultTextFormat = tf1;
myTXTh5.defaultTextFormat = tf1;
//myTXTh5s.defaultTextFormat = tf1;

}
```

Comment: What output do you get and what output format are you looking to get

Answer (score 1):

flash.globalization.CurrencyFormatter

[CurrencyFormatter.html](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/beta/reference/actionscript/3/flash/globalization/CurrencyFormatter.html)